# Spark's takeSample() results in two stages

Tags: apache-spark, sample

I've observed interesting behavior in Spark 1.3.1, the reason for which is not clear.

Doing something as simple as `sc.textFile("...").takeSample(...)` always results in two stages:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this and the key is to focus on the `details` expansion. The first and second have different line numbers for their call within `takeSample`. The first is [Line 428](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.3/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L428), which is a call to `count`, thus why this triggers on its own. The second is [Line 447](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.3/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L447), which is the call to `sample` itself. This might be confusing and could possibly be fixed, but I wouldn't imagine it to be a high priority.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Looking at the code for `takeSample`, it's quite possible to see even more stages - there are other actions that can be triggered under some conditions.